# Missing argument for paramater #1 in call

Tags: swift, function, arguments, swift2

I have this function and variable:

```
var trianglePlacement: CGFloat

func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat) {
    trianglePlacement = trianglePlacementVal
}
```

I use the function later to do a calculation for this variable:

```
var trianglePosition: CGFloat = setPlacmentOfTriangle() * width
```

I am getting a `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` error, okay makes sense, I am not passing in an argument.

Is there are way to get rid of the error without getting rid of the argument *and* not passing in an argument? These are the only times they show up in my code.

In case you are curious, this is the variable `width`:

```
var width: CGFloat = self.menubar.frame.size.width
```

Comment: Because setPlacmentOfTriangle: has no return value, your calculation will fail anyhow.   I'd recommend:                                                                     func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    trianglePlacement = trianglePlacementVal,
    return trianglePlacement
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way you can call the function without passing in an argument. You can provide a default value to the function parameter like so:

```
func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat = 1.0) {
    trianglePlacement = trianglePlacementVal
}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
setPlacmentOfTriangle()
```

If you call the setPlacmentOfTriangle function, it will use a value of 1.0 anytime you don't provide your own argument.

I would guess that this is a simplified example, but this function is not necessary at all. You really should just set the value of trianglePlacement directly, and not use a function like you are. Also, this line won't work:

```
var trianglePosition: CGFloat = setPlacmentOfTriangle() * width
```

The setPlacmentOfTriangle function doesn't return a value, so there is nothing to multiply with width.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is not very functional, avoid mutating other scopes
var trianglePlacement: CGFloat = 0

func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat) {
    trianglePlacement = trianglePlacementVal
}
```

---

```
// this is better
var trianglePlacement: CGFloat = 0

func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return trianglePlacementVal
}
```

---

```
// this is a function with a default  param value
var trianglePlacement: CGFloat = 0

func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat = 0.0) -> CGFloat {
    return trianglePlacementVal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `setPlacmentOfTriangle` should take in a `CGFloat` as a parameter and you're not sending it one

If you do not always want to pass an argument then you can make it optional like so:

```
func setPlacmentOfTriangle(trianglePlacementVal: CGFloat?) {
    if let tri = trianglePlacementVal as? CGFloat {
        trianglePlacement = tri 
    }
}
```

Then you can pass `nil` as your parameter:

```
setPlacmentOfTriangle(nil)
```